# CSS triangles getting cut off

Tags: css

I'm trying to create some CSS triangles, using css and the :after pseudo class. Somehow, the up and down arrows are working properly, but the left and right arrows are being "cut off" (see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K9vxN/ )

This is basically the css I'm using:

```
.arrow-right:after {
    content:"";
    border-top: 60px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
    border-left: 60px solid green;
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Is there a need to use after pseudo class?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to make a play button which consists of a triangle inside a circle. This will prevent me from having to use extra HTML since I can use the div itself to create the circle, and the after pseudo class for the triangle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make the `:after` pseudo element `inline-block` (or `block`). Currently it's an inline element, and it's size is based on the line height of the (empty) text it contains.

You'll have to fix some positioning then, though, but that should be trivial.

```css
div { height:0px; }
div:after { content:""; display: block;}

.arrow-up:after {
  margin-left: 50px; /* move right, to show it */
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-left: 15px solid transparent;
 border-right: 15px solid transparent;
 
 border-bottom: 15px solid black;
}

.arrow-down:after  {
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-left: 20px solid transparent;
 border-right: 20px solid transparent;
 
 border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}

.arrow-right:after {
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-top: 60px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
 
 border-left: 60px solid green;
}

.arrow-left:after {
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-top: 10px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
 
 border-right:10px solid blue; 
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-up"></div>
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
<div class="arrow-left"></div>
<div class="arrow-right"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K9vxN/2/

By the way, you might not need to use `:after` at all, but that depends on whether you want the div to *have* an arrow or to *be* an arrow. That's up to you. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Simply add `display: block` to all your `:after` selectors.  For example

```
.arrow-up:after {
    display: block; /* Added this */
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K9vxN/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the :after pseudo-element is specified as either `block` or `inline-block`, dependent upon your usage scenario.

```
div:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/kFa6a/

Answer (score 1):

your pseudo-element needs layout to be triggered:
you can set as `display:block;` or any other value of display but inline.
You can use as well `float` or `position:absolute`/`fixed` to trigger layout.
http://jsfiddle.net/K9vxN/5/

```
div:after {
 content:"";
display:block;/* or table, inline-table,inline-block, but not inline*/
/* to your choice, where it suits design the best */
/* pick up here instead display*/
/*position:absolute;*//* or fixed */;
/* float:left;*//* or right */
}
```